# Segmentation fault in C code using `string` from cs.50.h

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, cs50, caesar-cipher

I have a program here where I'm trying to decode a string of letters using a ceasar cipher; essentially I'm moving each character in the string "down" a letter ("a" -> "b", "f" -> "g", "z" -> "a").

The amount that I move a letter down depends on the key I give it.

In this specific program, I have a secret coded message hardcoded into the main() function, and a for loop iterating through each possible key.

The idea is that if this secret message is simply shifted downward by x amount of letters, spitting out 25 versions of the cipher will reveal an intelligible answer.

Unfortunately I'm using some concepts that are new to me - argc, argv, and multiple functions in one program. I am very new to this.

Can someone help explain the segmentation fault error I'm getting? I don't think I'm causing any overflows on arguments.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>

string decode(int key, string message);

int main(void)
{
    string secret_message = "ueuag rKJ AGIQ GIAR FEgN";

    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    {
        decode(i, secret_message);
        printf("%s", secret_message);
    }

    return 0;
}

string decode(int key, string message)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < strlen(message); i++)
    {
        if (message[i] >= 'a' && message[i] <= 'z')
        {
            message[i] = ((message[i] - 97 + key) % 26) + 97;
        }
        else if (message[i] >= 'A' && message[i] <= 'Z')
        {
            message[i] = ((message[i] - 65 + key) % 26) + 65;
        }
    }

    return message;
}
```

Comment: This `for (i = 0; i < strlen(message); i++)` is expensive, `strlen()` too loops through the `message` pointer.

Comment: Not knowing its definition, I guess passing `string` directly to `printf` isn't good.

Comment: Which language are you using, C or C++?  What is `string`?

Comment: What is `string`??? Where is it declared? And to avoid unnecessary confusion with `std::string` I'd remove [C++] tag from this. This is not C++..

Comment: It looks like `string` is a typedef of `char*` from [`cs50.h`](http://dkui3cmikz357.cloudfront.net/library50/c/cs50-library-c-3.0/cs50.h), a _popular_ library for a Computer Science course.

Comment: Wow.. that's a really bad idea when trying to teach people C.

Comment: @rodrigo: In that case [C++] tag has no business being here.

Comment: It's [tag:c] and `string` is defined as `char *` in *cs50.h*!

Comment: Alright guys, tags changed accordingly, and like rogrigo said I'm using a library or two from CS50. I'm well aware I won't be using "string" in the "real world", so I've change it to char *variable_name and I'm still having the same problem.
Should I change my code in OP, or is that... uncouth?

Comment: @DavidHoelzer And it's really common actually. It causes infinite confusion, and as you all could see the OP tagged as [tag:c++] which make it even more confusing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why is `string` a bad idea for a type in [c](/questions/tagged/c)?, here you can see an example. You are modifying a string literal and you shouldn't. Doing it invokes undefined behavior. Instead of having a `string` type you should treat strings as what they are in [c](/questions/tagged/c).

Instead do it like this

```
char secret_message[] = "ueuag rKJ AGIQ GIAR FEgN";
```

And the decode function

```
char *decode(int key, char *message)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; message[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if (message[i] >= 'a' && message[i] <= 'z')
        {
            message[i] = ((message[i] - 97 + key) % 26) + 97;
        }
        else if (message[i] >= 'A' && message[i] <= 'Z')
        {
            message[i] = ((message[i] - 65 + key) % 26) + 65;
        }
    }

    return message;
}
```

As you can see I am treating the string as an array because that's what it is, an array of bytes with a `'\0'` at the end. If you knew this you would never do something like `typedef char * string` because it's very misleading.

In *cs50.h* `string` is a `typedef` for a `char` pointer, and a pointer is not a string, a string is a sequence of bytes and a `char *` pointer can point to an array of `char` which could be a string if you define it and initialize it correctly. But a `char *` pointer could point to a string literal, and you can't alter them which is not clear if you define it as

```
string string_literal = "Do not attempt to modify me, it's undefined behavior";
```

When declaring a pointer to a string literal you should use `const char *` to avoid accidentaly trying to modify it.

Also, `typedef`ing pointers in my opinion has no benefit at all and causes a lot of confusion, a pointer is a pointer and must have a `*` near it's identifier when declared, if you remove the need for a `*` you can easily overlook pointers in the code and be confused.

Comment: Thanks for your informative comment. I've changed all <string> to <char *> and have the same problem

Comment: @DavidManess Please keep reading as I update the answer, see my suggestion -> "*You can't overwrite a string literal*".

Comment: @DavidManess Changing `string` to `char*` won't help, because `string` is a typedef to `char*` already. You need to declare your `secret_message` as a `char[]`, not a `char*` (or `string`), then the program will work.

Comment: @Paul and adding to your comment, you can initialize an array with a string literal, it would create a copy of the string literal that you can actually modify.

Comment: @Paul thanks, that worked. iharob thank you for your time and explanations.

Comment: @iharob you were a great help so thanks for teaching me that about chars and strings

Comment: @DavidManess Don't try to understand working with C strings (and pointers in general) by example. Read a good book that will explain it fundamentally (like the difference between `char[]` and `char*`, etc.).

Comment: @Paul I try to do as much googling as possible about new concepts I learn about. I'm taking a CS50x course (free) and unfortunately a book on C is a little bit out of my budget right now. I'll try and read more about it.